# A tool or script for changing the name of all tables and fields in a mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I am looking for a way to change all table names and field names of a huge mysql database. So, are there any tools or scripts for addressing it?

Comment: MySQLWorkbench is your friend.

Comment: is there a rule how to change tablenames and fieldnames ?

Comment: I'm using DB Forge Studio for manual editing